# How to replace the text of an i tag?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML as shown

```
<button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn blue">
   <i id="editorsave" class="icon-ok"></i>Save</button>
```

i want to replace the text of Save to Edit

This is the way i tried .

```
$('#editorsave').text('');
$('#editorsave').text('Edit');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amr88nLo/

could anybody please help me

Comment: The text doesn't appear to be in the i tag to begin with, are you sure you're asking the right question?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't put the text "Save" inside the `<i>` element you're trying to modify.

This could be fixed by making your `<button>` like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn blue">
  <i id="editorsave" class="icon-ok">Save</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the text is not in the `i` element, it is in its next sibling.

One solution is to change the contents of its next sibling like

```js
$('#editorsave')[0].nextSibling.data = 'Edit'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn blue">
  <i id="editorsave" class="icon-ok"></i>Save
</button>
```

---

Another is to use another element which will wrap the text alone and then change its content like

```js
$('#savebtn span').text('Edit')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn blue">
  <i id="editorsave" class="icon-ok"></i><span>Save</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer:

```
<button type="submit" id="savebtn" class="btn blue">Save</button>
```

```
$('#savebtn').html('<i class="icon-ok">Edit</i>')>
```